# Inkscape: Break apart doesn't break apart lines

Tags: inkscape, path

Breaking apart a line made of multiple lines doesn't separate it into individual lines.

I have a line made of multiple line segments (not a group, its one object). I select the line and do "Path" -> "Break Apart". Nothing happens, the lines are still one connected object, not individual lines.

Comment: That's not what break apart is for. It's a path operation which breaks apart compound paths - basically the opposite of creating a compound path. It doesn't break nodes apart.

Answer (score 3):

The action that needs to be done is "Break path at selected nodes".

Using the "Edit paths by nodes" tool: *select the line* -> *select each node in the line* (shortcut ctrl+a) -> *press* "Break path at selected nodes"

[image]